# Como armazenar um int e um string completo de dentro de um input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu desejo que na hora de digitar na variável **N** a palavra "2 suco de laranja" o prorgama armazene nas variáveis **numero** e **alimento**:

numero = 2 (de preferência inteiro, mas qualquer coisa eu converto ele depois)

alimento = "suco de alimento"

O código está abaixo e foi até onde consegui chegar:

```
suco_laranja = "suco de laranja"
morango = "morango fresco"
mamao = "mamao"
goiaba = "goiaba vermelha"
manga = "manga"
laranja = "laranja"
brocolis = "brocolis"


T = int(input(""))
for i in range(T):
    N = input()
    numero, alimento = N.split()

print(numero)
print(alimento)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) para separar a string pela primeira ocorrência do caractere que você passar como parâmetro, no caso você quer separar pelo caractere de espaço da string. Exemplo:

```
entrada = '2 sucos de laranja'
numero, _, alimento = entrada.partition(' ')
print(numero)
print(alimento)
```

Resultado:

> 2
>   sucos de laranja

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MTCWZo).

Assim você pode ter número com mais de 1 dígito que seu código ainda funcionará corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Caso o número sempre seja o primeiro elemento do input digitado, uma forma simples de resolver isso seria usar o slicing.

```
N = N.split()
numero = int(N[0])
alimento = ' '.join(N[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Também pode ser feita dessa forma, parecida com a que você tentou.

Separando a quantidade e o produto a partir da vírgula.

```
numero,alimento = input("> ").split(', ')

print(numero)
print(alimento)
```

**saída:**

```
>>> > 1, suco
>>> 1
>>> suco
```