# Entrada, na mesma linha, de uma string sem espaços e outra com espaços

Tags: python, input, dicionário, entrada-de-dados

Meu programa pede que, na entrada, numa mesma linha, haja uma *string* sem espaços
nome, o nome do depositante, e uma *string* que pode conter espaços desc, a descrição do objeto depositado. De modo que, depois, eu crie um dicionário para relacionar o nome e o objeto.

Ex entrada:
Ana Bolsa azul

Contudo, da forma que eu fiz, só é possível entrar com uma palavra no local da descrição do objeto. Como proceder para entrar com mais de uma palavra em desc??

Como fiz:

```
dic={}

nome,desc=input().split()

dic.update({nome:desc})
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como armazenar um int e um string completo de dentro de um input?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209062/como-armazenar-um-int-e-um-string-completo-de-dentro-de-um-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode alterar o split para quebrar apenas na primeira ocorrência

Como vai ficar o seu código:

```
dic={}

nome,desc=input().split(" ", 1)

dic.update({nome:desc})
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! (: